# Fatal error when trying to pass data to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, pass-data

In order to practice my networking, I built an app with a text field where you can input something. I use the wikipedia API to fetch the definition of that term / name/ expression. My goal is to then display that definition into another view controller.

A button performs the segue to the new view controller, where a label displays that definition.

The get request works, but when tapping the button, I get a fatalError : "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".

I would like to add that the error is displayed in the "prepare for segue" function.

Here is the code for my first view controller

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textEntryLabel: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    //MARK: - Relevant variables
    let wikipediaURl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    var termDefinitionInfo: String = ""
    let segueName: String = "toDefinition"

    @IBAction func buttonToDefinition(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // on fait la requete ici
        httpCall(termDefinition: textEntryLabel.text ?? "nothing to pass")

        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueName , sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueName {
            let secondVC = segue.destination as! DefinitionViewController

            secondVC.definitionLabel.text = termDefinitionInfo

        }
    }

    //MARK: - NETWORKING

      func httpCall(termDefinition: String) {
          let parameters : [String:String] = [
                 "format" : "json",
                 "action" : "query",
                 "prop" : "extracts",
                 "exintro" : "",
                 "explaintext" : "",
                 "titles" : termDefinition,
                 "indexpageids" : "",
                 "redirects" : "1",
                 ]

          //
          request(wikipediaURl, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
              if response.result.isSuccess {
                //1. on affiche le tableau json initial
                let definitionJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value)
                print(definitionJSON)

                // deux valeurs : pageID et definition
                let pageId = definitionJSON["query"]["pageids"][0].stringValue
                let pageDefinition = definitionJSON["query"]["pages"][pageId]["extract"].stringValue
                self.termDefinitionInfo = pageDefinition
                print(self.termDefinitionInfo)

              } else {
                print("Error! Could not fetch data!")
            }
          }
      }


}
```

Here is the code for the second view controller

````
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var definitionLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: Try to avoid force down casting

In your case you are trying to assign a value to an IBOutlet when it's not wired to its parent view controller. You better do this:

```
class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionLabel: UILabel!
    var labelValue: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        definitionLabel.text = labelValue
    }
}
```

And in your first view:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueName {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? DefinitionViewController {
          secondVC.labelValue = termDefinitionInfo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally agree with this *Tip: Try to avoid force down casting* if it's design mistake, then you will "*hide*" your bugs by scaring forcing.

Comment: i edited my code by following your advice @maysam and I no longer get an error in the 'prepare for segue'. however, I still do not manage to pass the data to the second view controller.

Comment: You don't get the passed data? How come? replace `var labelValue: String?` with `var labelValue: String? { didSet { print("*value set*") } }` and see if it prints anything in the console.